# how best to refactor two classes with lots of conditional logic?

Tags: ruby, oop, architecture

I have an Event class which holds start and end times for an event. Each Event object can have a number of associated ChildEvent objects representing each recurrence of the parent Event.  Each of those classes needs to take a different action based on how they are being edited e.g.

Deleting just one Event:

- Event: make the first child the parent of all other children before deleting
- ChildEvent: just delete as normal

Deleting an Event and all subsequent events:

- Event: delete all child events then delete itself
- ChildEvent: delete all future siblings then delete itself

Editing just one Event:

- Event: make the first child the parent of all other children then update
- ChildEvent: update itself as usual

Editing an Event and all subsequent events:

- Event: update all child events then update itself
- ChildEvent: update all future siblings then update itself

At present I'm achieving this through checking for conditions and taking appropriate action but it's starting to get messy (there are other conditions with associated behaviours too).  I'm curious to know how more experienced programmers would handle this (I'm using ruby). Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand at all.  Could you be more concrete?

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a case for the [specification pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) to encapsulate your logic

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just link the events, in the form of a doubly linked list?

An Event would have a `previous` and a `next` slot (nil if first or last of a chain).

Deleting just one Event (`delete`):

- set the `previous` slot of `next` Event to the `previous` slot of this Event
- set the `next` slot of the `previous` Event to the `next` slot of this Event
- delete this Event

Deleting an Event and all subsequent events (`delete-all`):

- Delete this Event
- set `next` slot of `previous` Event to nil
- recurse on `next` Event
- until `next` is nil

Editing just one Event (`edit`):

- edit this Event
- set `previous` slot of `next` Event to `previous` slot of this Event
- set `next` slot of `previous` Event to `next` slot of this Event

Editing an Event and all subsequent events (`edit-all`):

- if initial call, set `next` slot of `previous` Event to nil
- edit this Event
- recurse on `next` Event
- until `next` is nil

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a different object model. Instead of `Events` and `ChildEvents` you could look at it as `EventType`s and `Event`s.

```
EventType  # Has many Events
---------
name
# ...

Event      # Belongs to EventType
-----
event_id
start_time
end_time
# ...
```

Then your editing operations would be greatly simplified.

Find previous Event...

```
Event.find(:first, :conditions => [
  'event_type_id = ? AND start_time > ?',
  event.type.id,
  event.start_time],
  :order => 'ASC'
)
```

Delete an Event and all subsequent events of that type...

```
events_to_delete = Event.find(:all, 
  :conditions => [
    'event_type_id = ? AND start_time >= ?', 
    event.event_type.id,
    event.start_time
  ])

Event.destroy( all_events_to_delete.map { |event| event.id } )
```